# Execute npm Script in a different Folder with python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, os.system

Can someone tell me how I can do "npm run start" in any folder using a Python script. But please with the "os" operator and not "subprocess".

**EDIT:**
I need a python script, that goes to a specific folder and then executes
"npm run start". How can I do that?

Comment: what did you try? Did you get error message? Show it in question.

Comment: normally in system variable `PATH` you should add full path to folder with `npm` (I will repeat: `folder`, not program `npm`) and then you can run in any folder, in any language.

Comment: I need a python script, that goes to a specific folder and then executes "npm run start". How can I do that?

Comment: did you try `os.chdir(...)` before `os.system()` ? Or system command `cd ... && npm ...` or `cd ... ; npm ...` ?

Comment: Thanks for that, got it with os.chdir(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run code in selecte folder

```
os.chdir("path/to/folder")
os.system("npm run start")
```

or

```
os.system("cd path/to/folder ; npm run start") 

os.system("cd path/to/folder && npm run start")
```

or

```
subprocess.run("npm run start", shell=True, cwd="path/to/folder")

subprocess.run(["npm", "run", "start"], cwd="path/to/folder")
```

and similar way with other methods in `subprocess`